# Synchronized Key Word is not Guaranteeing Thread-Safe in My Case

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code is confusing me as synchronized key word is not preventing the two threads accessing SafeThread.value at the same time.

While I was running the code, the result is not 20000 as expected.

I also tried to make increment() non static and have the two threads have the same instance of SafeThread. It did not work either. Did I miss anything?

```
public class MultithreadTesting extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultithreadTesting thread1 = new MultithreadTesting();
        MultithreadTesting thread2 = new MultithreadTesting();
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        System.out.println(SafeThread.value);
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 10000;
        while (i > 0) {
            SafeThread.increment();
            i--;
        }
    }
}


public class SafeThread {
    public static int value = 0;
    public synchronized static void increment() {
        value++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know? The code in the question doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Your `main` thread is dying before `thread1` and `thread2`, though. When I change your main method to add `thread1.join(); thread2.join(); System.out.println(SafeThread.value);` after starting threads, it prints `2000`, which I assume should be expected.

Comment: Hi Ernest. It is exactly as you said, the main thread reached System.out.println before the two threads finished. The number I saw in console was before the two threads added 10000 respectively. I added thread1.join(); thread2.join() in main function and it worked. Thank you Ernest.